# Java 8 LocalDateTime deserialized using Gson

Tags: java, json, java-8, gson

I have JSONs with a date-time attribute in the format "2014-03-10T18:46:40.000Z", which I want to deserialize into a java.time.LocalDateTime field using Gson.

When I tried to deserialize, I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

Comment: Is this happening during serialization or de-serialization. If it's the second - check if your json is valid - for example it has to start with `{` (aka BEGIN_OBJECT), but instead your json starts with a character

Comment: I make a mistake its during de-serialization. Json -> Object. But I think my Json is ok. If I replace in my object my attribute LocalDateTime with String it works.

Comment: json has the format `{"key":"value"}` Your json is definitely invalid. As I said in gson `{` is `BEGIN_OBJECT` and it says that it;s missing. Just `println()` the json to check if it's correct.

Also you can print the `serialized` object to see how the json should look like :)

Comment: Ok I understand now why it doesn't work. But maybe you know if there is something I can do? Like a special options with Gson for say if I have a String with a special Date and Time to deserialize this field and create the object I need?

Comment: I cannot tell you anything before I see the string. But either way, you cannot de-serialize it unless it;s valid json. IMHO the best (and maybe the only) thing you can do is to make this string valid json.

Comment: The String is like this: "2014-03-10T18:46:40.000Z". So I need to get an Object of this (datetime object from mysql?).

Comment: Have you thought about that the timestamp string looks like an UTC-ISO-8601 global timestamp (letter Z at the end!)? It is not a local timestamp representation. I can actually not test the conversion to a `LocalDateTime` (no Java 8 with me) but suppose that this conversion might fail.

Comment: @fische: As Meno says, what you have is an `OffsetDateTime`, not a `LocalDateTime`. Also, you might like to look at my custom serialisers for `java.time` entities: https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers

Answer (score 53):

The error occurs when you are deserializing the LocalDateTime attribute because GSON fails to parse the value of the attribute as it's not aware of the LocalDateTime objects.

Use GsonBuilder's registerTypeAdapter method to define the custom LocalDateTime adapter.
Following code snippet will help you to deserialize the LocalDateTime attribute.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong());
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}).create();
```

Answer (score 35):

To extend @Randula's answer, to parse a zoned date time string (2014-03-10T18:46:40.000Z) to JSON:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
@Override
public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString()).toLocalDateTime();
}
}).create();
```

Comment: that parameter to deserialize of type "Type"  what is that exactly?

Comment: @mcgyver5 - it's a `java.lang.reflect.Type`

Comment: it is not a zoned date time string, but the instant (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: The input string is fits neither of the two classes you used. `LocalDateTime` ignores the input’s indicator `Z` of a pn offset form UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. `ZonedDateTime` is for representing a date-time in the context of a time zone, but the input has no time zone. The appropriate classes for this input are `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 33):

To even further extend @Evers answer:

You can further simplify with a lambda like so:

```
GSON GSON = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, (JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>) (json, type, jsonDeserializationContext) ->
    ZonedDateTime.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString()).toLocalDateTime()).create();
```

Answer (score 8):

Following worked for me.

**Java:**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() { 
@Override 
public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException { 

return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")); } 

}).create();

Test test = gson.fromJson(stringJson, Test.class);
```

where ***stringJson*** is a Json which is stored as String type

**Json:**

> "dateField":"2020-01-30 15:00"

where ***dateField*** is of ***LocalDateTime*** type which is present in the stringJson String variable.

Comment: Will this work if I have other type, like String/Integer key values in the json?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, you could also use already available serializer.

https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers

You include it in your project.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fatboyindustrial.gson-javatime-serialisers</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson-javatime-serialisers</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then include it to the GsonBuilder process

```
final Gson gson = Converters.registerOffsetDateTime(new GsonBuilder()).create();
final OffsetDateTime original = OffsetDateTime.now();

final String json = gson.toJson(original);
final OffsetDateTime reconstituted = gson.fromJson(json, OffsetDateTime.class);
```

Just in case its not clear, there exist different methods for different class types.

Comment: Recommend to use this one

Answer (score 1):

To further amplify @Nicholas Terry answer:

You might also need a serializer:

```java
String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
GSON gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(
        LocalDateTime.class,
        (JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>) (json, type, jsonDeserializationContext) ->
            ZonedDateTime.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString()).toLocalDateTime()
    )
    .registerTypeAdapter(
        LocalDateTime.class,
        (JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime>) (localDate, type, jsonSerializationContext) ->
            new JsonPrimitive(formatter.format(localDate)
    )
    .create();
```

Or the kotlin version:

```kotlin
val dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)
val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(
        LocalDateTime::class.java,
        JsonDeserializer { json, type, jsonDeserializationContext -> 
            ZonedDateTime.parse(json.asJsonPrimitive.asString).toLocalDateTime()
        } as JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime?>
    )
    .registerTypeAdapter(
        LocalDateTime::class.java,
        JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime?> { localDate, type, jsonDeserializationContext ->
            JsonPrimitive(formatter.format(localDate))
        }
    )
    .create()
```