# Class as a parameter when parsing a List with Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, typetoken

I need to parse a JSON array of objects into a list. I would pass

```
Class<?> classToParse
```

as a parameter. According to [Converting ZonedDateTime type to Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408192/converting-zoneddatetime-type-to-gson), I need something like

```
Type listType =  new TypeToken<List<ExampleClass>>() {}.getType();
```

to use with

```
 gsonInstance.fromJson(output, listType);
```

But how can I specify my "classToParse" (a parameter) instead of the hardcoded ExampleClass? I cannot insert it as is.

Comment: You can't do that. But you can merely pass `TypeToken<List<ConcreteClass>>(){}.getType()` instances and not `Class` instances for every particular `fromJson(...)` call.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot substitute the type parameter at the compile type with runtime invocations -- type information along with type parameters are generated by Java compiler at the compile time.

First off, note *how* `Gson.fromJson(...)` overloads are declared: neither uses `TypeToken` as a parameter, but they can accept `Type` -- this is fine, because `TypeToken`s are *not* mandatory to parse parameterized types JSONs, types matter only. Second, it's *really fine* to pass ready-to-use type `Type` instances to the `fromJson` method:

```java
final Foo foo = gson.fromJson(..., Foo.class);
final List<Foo> foos = gson.fromJson(..., new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){}.getType());
```

Note that in *both* cases literals are passed: the second one is just longer and created every time the line is executed. The `Type` interface does not provide any mutator methods, so you can consider it something that can be treated as a constant (as well as other value types ilke `String`s, `Integer`s, and so forth are):

```java
static final TypeToken<List<Foo>> fooListTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){};
...
final List<Foo> foos = gson.fromJson(..., fooListTypeToken.getType());
```

Or even shorter (however I prefer the previous way -- and I would recommend it to you [you can reuse the type token and not lose it]):

```java
static final Type fooListType = new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){}.getType();
...
final List<Foo> foos = gson.fromJson(..., fooListTypeToken);
```

How much `fooListTypeToken` and `Foo.class` differ from the programmatic point of view? Well, essentially no difference (except that the first one represents a list whilst the latter represents a concrete class, of course). Both are values.

However, if you want to get dynamic types by a given element class (or better a type) for any *must* reason, then you can create `Type` instances yourself and just pass them to `fromJson`:

```java
static ParameterizedType createJavaUtilListParameterizedType(final Type elementType) {
    return new ParameterizedType() {
        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
            return List.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[]{ elementType };
        }

        @Override
        public Type getOwnerType() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

The method just creates an anonymous implementation of `ParameterizedType` where:

- `getRawType()` - must return `java.util.List.class`, a container parameterized type
- `getActualTypeArguments()` - must return the element type; note that it always must return a new array in order not to be damaged elsewhere (since it's not a 0-length array)
- `getOwnerType()` - not implemented in this case and can safely return `null`.

So now the substitution is available at runtime:

```java
final List<Foo> foos = gson.fromJson(..., createJavaUtilListParameterizedType(Foo.class));
```

but

```
final List<Foo> foos = gson.fromJson(..., createJavaUtilListParameterizedType(new TypeToken<GenericElement<String, Integer>>(){}.getType()));
```

for parameterized types. Well, still does not differ much from holding `static final` references to type tokens and extracting the types from them later. And semantically it's the same as what the compiler does at compile time.

### Edit

Gson `TypeToken` also provides `static TypeToken<?> getParameterized(Type rawType, Type... typeArguments)` that can be used instead of own implementation of the parameterized type like:

```java
static ParameterizedType createJavaUtilListParameterizedType(final Type elementType) {
    return (ParameterizedType) TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, elementType).getType();
}
```