# Json file parses but I still receive exception:Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, unmarshalling

**Edit**
I've added the details class and fixed the duplicate key. The dates are in fact strings.

Using gson 2.8 and eclipse.

I managed to get the JSON file parsed and the values stored and printed,
but I still get the exception.
(BEGIN_OBJECT expected but was STRING at line 1 column 2)

I've checked other solutions,
like put an object where expected,
but it just throws a different exception. e.g (begin_array is expected)

**Json File**

```
[{"numValue1":"1",
"StringValue1":"EI",
"StringValue2":"A",
"enumValue1":"TYPE_A",
"numValue2":"3221",
"StringValue3":"DDEF",
"StringValue4":"Mexicof",
"numValue3":"8",
"stringDate1":"27/05/2017 11:55",
"stringDate2":"29/09/2016 11:55",
"stringDate3":"27/05/2017 11:57"}]
```

**Code used for parsing the file**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").create();
Details[] feedRecord = gson.fromJson(data.trim(), Details[].class);
```

**Details class**

```
public class Details implements Serializable {

enum Type {
    TYPE_D, TYPE_A
};

@SerializedName("numValue1")
private Integer num1;
@SerializedName("StringValue1")
private String string1; 
@SerializedName("StringValue2")
private String string2; 
@SerializedName("numValue2")
private String num2;
@SerializedName("StringValue3")
private String string3;
@SerializedName("StringValue4")
private String string3;
@SerializedName("numValue3")
private String num3;
@SerializedName("StringDate1")
private String date1;
@SerializedName("StringDate2")
private String date2;
@SerializedName("StringDate3")
private String date3;
@SerializedName("enumType1")
private Type enumType;
}
```

**Exception**

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $[0]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
```

Comment: How certain are you that the JSON you've shown here is *exactly* the content of `data`?

Comment: Well, you have a duplicate key, I don't know if this causes gson to fail though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1)

Comment: Make sure that the first character in your JSON is not actually an opening quote.

Comment: We can't see your `Detail` class

Comment: `BEGIN_ARRAY` *should be expected*, by the way, as that is what your data is, a list.

Comment: Include the Details class.  This is kind of important since gson is throwing the exception based on imput that is supposed to result in an instance of the Details class.

Comment: I suspect that the `Detail` class fields `Date2` and `Date3` are some kind of date *object*, not `String`, but JSON value is a *string* (e.g. `"29/09/2016 11:55"`), hence the error message `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`. Of course, since you haven't shared the `Detail` class with us, we can only guess. See [Java 8 LocalDateTime deserialized using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22310143/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

Using JsonParser, the exception is:(I modified the duplicate key)

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 252 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:na]
```

The Gson api states that the date pattern should follow

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html?is-external=true

This throws no exception:

```
String str = "[{\"numValue1\":\"1\",\"StringValue1\":\"EI\",\"StringValue2\":\"A\",\"enumValue1\":\"TYPE_A\",\"numValue11\":\"3221\",\"StringValue4\":\"DDEF\",\"StringValue5\":\"Mexicof\",\"numValue2\":\"8\",\"stringDate1\":\"27/05/2017 11:55\",\"Date2\":\"29/09/2016 11:55\",\"Date3\":\"27/05/2017 11:57\"}]\"";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").create();
JsonReader jr = gson.newJsonReader(new StringReader(str));


jr.beginArray();
jr.beginObject();
System.out.println(jr.nextName());
```

Column 252 is where date data begins