# Gson map LocalDateTime from json to Java Type

Tags: java, json, gson, mapping

I want to map the date from json to java. 
I annotated the property in my mapping class like this:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
@SerializedName("AdvancedDate")
private LocalDateTime advancedDate;
```

when this is executed it produces this error:

```
 java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-02-05T08:59:43.323'     could not be parsed at index 23
```

The input is: '2018-02-05T08:59:43.323'

Json structure:

TradeId":123,"SellerCompany":"ACME","Currency":"GBP","AdvancedDate":"2018-02-05T08:59:43.323","ExpectedPaymentDate":"2018-02-23T00:00:00","PercentageNotional":10.00000,"TradeFaceValue":1111.64,"AmountAdvanced":111.78000,"AmountOutstanding":589.78000,"PriceGrade":"4","AdvanceRate":85.00000000,"DiscountFee":0.800,"PaymentStatus":"Awaiting payment","MiInvestorFeePercentage":15.00000,"AuctionType":"Single/Select Invoice","CrystallisedLosses":0.0,"CrystallisedLossDate":null,"DelinquencyDate":null,"DiscountOn":"Advance","DebtorName":"Donald Trump","IsAdvanced":true

How to map this value to LocalDateTime without parsing errors?

Comment: can you provide us with the structure of json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 LocalDateTime deserialized using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310143/java-8-localdatetime-deserialized-using-gson)

Comment: json structure added

Comment: Has anyone an idea or what?

Comment: have you spent sometime to read the duplicated link ?

Comment: The other article brought me here but there is no error. I have found out, that my error comes from FieldUtils.getAllFields. Marking this as possible duplicate did not help.

Comment: you have to create custom adapter!

Comment: Ok thanks. I think i will do it without opencsv then.