# Deserialize date attribute of json into LocalDate

Tags: json, gson, deserialization, localdate

I am trying to de-serialize date attribute in json of format "2018-05-27" using Gson. I want date to be in LocalDate format after de-serialization.

For json input :

{
 "id" : 1,
 "name" : "test",
 "startDate" : "2018-01-01",
 "endDate" : "2018-01-05",
}

I am getting error for startDate and endDate :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 LocalDateTime deserialized using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310143/java-8-localdatetime-deserialized-using-gson)

Comment: "_The error occurs when you are deserializing the LocalDate[Time] attribute because GSON fails to parse the value of the attribute as it's not aware of the LocalDate[Time] objects._"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The way we can do this is :

```
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            public LocalDate deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
                return LocalDate.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
            }
        }).create();
```

and then

```
YourClassName yourClassObject = gson.fromJson(msg, YourClassName.class);
```

Comment: What if i have both a LocalDate and LocalDateTime in the json? Can we make the above functionality adapt to it?