# Gson Date Conversion

Tags: java, gson

I'm receiving the date in the format from the server is `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss` and I need to convert  to the date format `yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss` using Gson JsonDeserializer.

Example:

Received date from server: `20230320 16:09:05`

to be converted to: `2023-Mar-20 16:09:05`

I want to convert JSON to Java using Gson API

JSON

```json
{"service": 2,"userIP": "10.1.1.2.3","startDateTime": "20230321 12:55:44"}
```

Java class

```java
public class TestJava 
{ 
    private Long service;
    private String userIP;
    private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
    //setter and getter
}
```

Expected output as below

```
TestJava [service=2, userIP=10.1.1.2.3, startDateTime=2023-Mar-21 12:55:44]
```

Comment: A date in java has no format. Please share the related code!

Comment: I m not sure whats in your mind, but I dont think a JSON parser can convert date formats. You are looking for java.time library

Comment: @experimentunit1998X question updated ,please  check

Comment: Seems related: [Java 8 LocalDateTime deserialized using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310143/java-8-localdatetime-deserialized-using-gson) Did you search? What did you find?

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` does not have a format (its `toString()` will always use the ISO-8601 format. If you want to show a different format, you'll need to format it explicitly. Where are you having problems, converting from JSON, or displaying the `LocalDateTime`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read **and output** json.

Define a custom deserialiser as follows:

```
class LocalDateTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer < LocalDateTime > {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
    throws JsonParseException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsString(), 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
}
```

Define a custom serialiser as follows;

```
class LocalDateTimeSerializer implements JsonSerializer < LocalDateTime > { 
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(LocalDateTime localDateTime, Type srcType, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(formatter.format(localDateTime));
    }
}
```

String them together like this (for calling from static main):

```
private static Gson buildGson() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer());

    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();
    return gson;
}
```

Improve the definition of TestJava.toString() like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TestJava [service=" + service + ", userIP=" + userIP + ", startDateTime=" + formatter.format(startDateTime) + "]";
}

private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = buildGson();
    
    String inputValue = "{\"service\": 2,\"userIP\": \"10.1.1.2.3\",\"startDateTime\": \"20230321 12:55:44\"}";
    
    TestJava object = gson.fromJson(inputValue, TestJava.class);
    
    String outputValue = gson.toJson(object);
    
    System.out.println("Serialised: " + outputValue);
    
    System.out.println("toString: " + object);

}
```

Output:

```
Serialised: {
  "service": 2,
  "userIP": "10.1.1.2.3",
  "startDateTime": "2023-Mar-21 12:55:44"
}
toString: TestJava [service=2, userIP=10.1.1.2.3, startDateTime=2023-Mar-21 12:55:44]
```

Comment: The formatting of the `LocalDateTime` can be put in the `toString` method and/or other methods of the enclosing class (`TestJava` in the question) is desired (typically it would not be the most important part).

Comment: Your deserializer didn’t work for me. I got *com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.time.LocalDateTime#date' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.*

Comment: deserializer didn’t work for me to

Comment: The way I read [the docs](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat-java.lang.String-) `setDateFormat()` only affected serialization and deserialization of `Date` objects back when we used those a decade ago. You probably need to register a type adapter.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have corrected/rewritten my answer.

Comment: @OleV.V.  LocalDateTime object does not have a format.

Comment: Very true. [Jens said that in a comment already.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808978/gson-date-conversion/75809662?noredirect=1#comment133725405_75808978) It’s unclear to me whether the OP falsely thought it could have or they wanted string output in the mentioned format. Or maybe it didn’t matter at all.

Comment: I get `toString: TestJava [service=2, userIP=10.1.1.2.3, startDateTime=2023-mar.-21 12:55:44`. One will probably want to specify locale on the formatters. Otherwise your solution works the way you describe. +1